# How to load Complete google book url in webview?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I want to load google book url in my webview but it cuts and not load entier google book webpage. i want to open this [link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=UVz06fnwJvUC&pg=PA57&dq=google&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHjfKCgPvOAhXMRY8KHY-zBwEQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=google&f=false) in webview.

**Java code is,**

```
public class ItemClickResult extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

    Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
    String url = data.getString("url");

    final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}}
```

xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ItemClickResult">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am getting output like this and scroll which is not loaded both are like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlvmW.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

web_view.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

or

android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: not working the web page is loaded but book page section not loaded properly like in browser. the web page is perfect fit and when i open in chrome browse. I want same thing in my webview